# Change URL parameter without refreshing the page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have been trying to change a parameter of my URL without reloading the site, however, I am not 100% sure what's wrong with my code. What happens in the URL is removing all the parameters and replacing it for a simple string. 
i.e
http://localhost:50754/Signup555

And I want to change from http://localhost:50754/Signup?A=1&B=2&C=3 to http://localhost:50754/Signup?A=1&B=2&C=6

```
  function changeQueryString(searchString, documentTitle) {
        documentTitle = typeof documentTitle !== 'Pid' ? documentTitle : document.title;
        var urlSplit = (window.location.href).split("?");
        var obj = {
            Title: documentTitle,
            Url: urlSplit[0] + searchString
        };
        history.pushState(obj, obj.Title, obj.Url);
    }

<a onclick="changeQueryString('555', 'Pid')"> change it</a>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to modify the URL without reloading the page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/how-to-modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page)

Comment: No, it's using a different method and it includes a HTML button.

Comment: window.history.replaceState(null, null, window.location.pathname);

Comment: @RichardSocker what'd be the right correction? Or how would I replace that in my method?

Comment: Where do you send the parameters you want to replace in the url?

Comment: For the moment I was coding it like this <a onclick="changeQueryString('555', 'Pid')"> change it</a> The new value should be 555

Comment: I added an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a "router" library. [Navigo](https://github.com/krasimir/navigo) is a decent example.

Comment: I cannot use this because it's asp.net page. However I appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

Your function should be:

```
  function changeQueryString(searchString, documentTitle) {
     window.history.replaceState(null, null, window.location.pathname+"?A="+searchString[0]+"&B="+searchString[1]+"&C="+searchString[2]);
    }

<a onclick="changeQueryString('555', 'Pid')"> change it</a>
```